# Creating a custom navigation controller that controls two views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

So I am creating an app for iPhone and iPad. I am currently working on the iPhone version. I need to implement a custom navigation controller that controls only both view controllers that are on the screen. It's better to demonstrate the situation with a few pictures.

[image]

[image: Pictures]

So what I want to do is have a navigation controller that can control both of my view controllers and I can push a new view controller on the bottom or on the top with the other staying as it is. I have no problem with doing the basic code like pushing a new view controller, animating the transition etc. What I am asking is more about the "correct way" of making this. Also how can I link the IBOutlets in navigation controller to the custom view controllers in Xcode, if I try to drag it to my view controller, it won't let me, I think it's because they're in different groups(see picture 2). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to find out about View Controllers Containment API introduced in iOS 5, IIRC.

Comment: I am reading the reference at the moment, but right now it seems that I have to setup the custom navigation controller programmatically using UIStoryboard identifiers.

Comment: Storyboard is a convenience, but it can't handle a good number of special customizations so don't be afraid to use code.

Comment: Yeah. I basically created a custom viewcontroller that does what I want. It wasn't really as hard as I thought it would be.